# Unable to understand the value change of a variable pizzaNum

Tags: java, java-threads

In this code below I am trying to make 10 pizzaz (as the value of `pizzaNum` becomes 10) and then serve them form different threads (I just used one thread for question), but just in the start of run method the value of `pizzaNum` becomes **0**. Why? I am unable to understand this.

```
public class NewDiningHall {
    static int pizzaNum; 
    static int studentID;

    public void makePizza() {
        pizzaNum++; 
    }

    static class PizzaServe extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            System.out.println("Before run "+pizzaNum);
            String result; 
            if (pizzaNum > 0) { 
               result = "Served "; 
               pizzaNum--; 
            } 
            else
                result = "Starved "; 
            System.out.println(pizzaNum+" "+result + studentID); 
            studentID++; 
        } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        NewDiningHall d = new NewDiningHall(); 
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            d.makePizza();
        } 
        System.out.println(d.pizzaNum);
        PizzaServe t1 = new PizzaServe();
        t1.start();
    } 
}
```

Output:

> 10
>   Before run 0
>   0 Starved 0

Comment: Is `DiningHall` related to `NewDiningHall`?

Comment: Where is DiningHall? Could it be that you are increasing count in DiningHall class rather than NewDiningHall static member?

Answer (score 1):

First of all rename with

```
public class DiningHall {
```

and run it, because I have received as output

```
10
Before run 10
9 Served 0
```

so it works!

Bye